# How fitting is the term "Unruly allies" to describe a group of people with different alignments/interests

Tags: meaning

English is not my native language, so I have a bit of a hard time figuring out how fitting the term is:

Can "unruly allies" / "unruly alliance" describe a group of people with completly different alignments/interests forced to stick togheter for some reason? Can it be used to describe a temporary alliance that will fall appart as soon as it's possible?

The easiest way I could describe something like this is (in the D&D alingment sence) something like a "neutral evil" (completly self centered) character allied with "good" aligned characters, both sides depending on each other to get through some sort of otherwise unsolvable scenario.

Would the term "Unruly Allies" fit that, or are there better choices?

Comment: *Alliance of necessity* works without judging the goals and is probably the term you want. Possibly *unholy alliance*, especially if the goals of the alliance are 'bad.'  Unruly allies would be more used to describe allies who don't necessarily follow the leader and may work at cross purposes, not that they necessarily have different interests..

Comment: "Unlikely allies".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unruly allies" just means that the allies, whoever they are, are undisciplined. It says nothing about whether their motives are alike.

I up-voted Ben W for his suggestion of unholy allies. It seems like a very good solution in your specific context.

> An unholy alliance popularly refers to an alliance which is perceived as unnatural, unusual, or simply undesirable, sometimes between seemingly antagonistic parties.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unholy_alliance_(geopolitical))

Comment: Yes, unholy alliance seems to be the best term for something like that, even if (to me, as not native english speaker) it sounds like something bound to religious aspects (holy / unholy) instead of political oppinions. But in the end it's still the better fitting one ;)

Comment: In my experience there is no allusion to religion. Compare the expression, "He's got himself into an unholy mess" -  http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unholy+mess

Answer (score 3):

"Unruly allies" are nominally on your side but are hard to control.  From [*The Oxford Handbook of the French Revolution*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MxUoBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA524&dq=%22unruly%20allies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBmoVChMI6cnso7PlxgIVUQ6SCh0KOgIS#v=onepage&q=%22unruly%20allies%22&f=false) edited by David Andress:

> Having accepted assistance from reactionary activists known as gilded
>   youth during the popular insurgency of Germinal and Prairial, they [the deputies of the National Convention, the national assembly]
>   found the young men to be ever more **unruly allies**.

(Germinal and Prairial were months in the French Revolutionary calendar.  The latter ran from May 20 to June 18; the former ran from March 22 to April 19)

Answer (score 3):

I like the term unruly allies. It is clear that they are allies but that they are difficult to control as a group. It is not the same as unholy allies, who are allies united in one particular purpose but who are essentially antagonistic to each other.

Comment: thanks for the answer ( "unholy allies" )! I had to decide between two (since you sadly can't select multiple answers after all) and took the earlier / quoted one - but yours is basically just as correct!

Answer (score 1):

I've frequently heard the term [***uneasy allies***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uneasy+allies%2Cunruly+allies%2Cunlikely+allies&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuneasy%20allies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunruly%20allies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunlikely%20allies%3B%2Cc0). Turns out there's also a book by that title, an episode of Star Trek Online, and numerous other usages.[*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uneasy%20allies%22)

Answer (score 1):

**Unruly** is defined as something that cannot easily be controlled, governed, managed and so on...  something quite disruptive and annoying.

> Joe's apartment was filled with unruly cockroaches

It's not to say that the cockroaches cannot be exterminated and killed, but rather that the cockroaches will not succumb to you.  You cannot train cockroaches.

An unruly mob is something you hear a lot, which is basically just a group or crowd of people that is so populated that stopping them would be a quite the job.

**An unruly ally** is, yes, an ally.  But they are the worst ally.  Something, or anything, that they do is outright disturbing and disagreeable.  Although the unruly ally could still possibly be somehow coerced to do something not unruly.

### *Disobedient*